# Removing substrings from java StringBuilder

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I want to remove all the IP information from the below string.

```java
StringBuilder s=new StringBuilder("Comment by : hihi(ip:1.23.34.5)
                Comment by : rohi(ip:1.23.48.45)
                Comment by : ro 
                Comment by : rosehi(ip:12.39.80.345)Tue Jul 30 10:06:31 EDT 2019 
                Comment by : YES(ip:1.23.72.4345) 
                Comment by : kuhTue Jul 30 10:38:24 EDT 2019
                Comment by : testipcomment(ip:12.56.7.3345)");
```

**Expected Output:-**

```
"Comment by : hihi
 Comment by : rohi
 Comment by : ro 
 Comment by : rosehiTue Jul 30 10:06:31 EDT 2019 
 Comment by : YES 
 Comment by : kuhTue Jul 30 10:38:24 EDT 2019
 Comment by : testipcomment"
```

Comment: You may want to read up on regular expressions. When you have a regex, use the `.toString().replaceAll()`.

Comment: How you get the IP information into your string?

Comment: In case of chat type message, do not append the IP that you are getting. I think somewhere, you are appending the IP address.

Comment: @Sambit No i'm not appending the ips in a chat. Just storing in DB.

Comment: @DushyantTankariya I used request.getRemoteAddr() to get ip address and appended to the string.

Comment: So, here I'm confused first you are appending the IP address to string and then you want it to remove why? Are you doing something else process on it after appending string and before remove IP from a string? If not then I'll suggest you remove append operation.

Comment: @DushyantTankariya I am storing the comments made by support team regarding fixing of issues and storing in the DB. I am also appending the ip of the support team members who have made the issue fix in order to know who exactly fixed the issue. Later on I am displaying comment history for the particular issue on an interface and dont want the ip to be displayed.

Comment: That makes sense, Now, You have your answer which can implement in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will give you the desired result.

```
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("Comment by : hihi(ip:123345)Comment by : rohi(ip:1234845)Comment by : ro Comment by : rosehi(ip:123980345)Tue Jul 30 10:06:31 EDT 2019 Comment by : YES(ip:123724345) Comment by : kuhTue Jul 30 10:38:24 EDT 2019Comment by : testipcomment(ip:125673345)");
    String str = s.toString().replaceAll("\\(ip:\\d+\\)", "");
    System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: Thanks this works! I am using replaceAll("\\(ip:\\d+\\.+\\d+\\.+\\d+\\.+\\d+\\)", "") to replace the ip configs which are dot separated like (ip:1.23.34.5)

Answer (score 0):

Use regex

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(ip:\\d+\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
System.out.println(m.replaceAll(""));
```

`ip:\\\d+` matches the `ip` followed by any number of digits.

Comment: The brackets will stay with this! The pattern should be `\\(ip:\\d+\\)`!